# Why can I not extend a class with ambiguous constructors in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have the following:

```
public class BogusSuper {
    public BogusSuper(Collection<String>... a) {}
    public BogusSuper(String... a) {}
}
```

And in another class, I do:

```
public class BogusSub extends BogusSuper {
   public BogusSub() {/*Prevent calling super's constructor*/}
```

}

When I try to compile, I get the error: "reference to BogusSuper is ambiguous, both constructor BogusSuper(java.util.Collection...) in BogusSuper and constructor BogusSuper(java.lang.String...) in BogusSuper match.

BogusSuper compiles just fine. Why does BogusSub have issues when I'm not actually calling any of BogusSuper's constructors? I've tried explicitly setting multiple constructors as well, none of which refer to the superclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have varargs parameters `(SomeType... arg)`, which is syntactic sugar for an array of `SomeType`. When you call such a method, the type is inferred from the parameter, but when you don't provide parameters the type can't be inferred, so both methods are equally a match.

The reason you are "calling" the constructor is because when you don't define a constructor, one is implicitly defined for you with no arguments, - the "default constructor" ie:

```
public BogusSub() {
}
```

And if you don't call a `super()` constructor explicitly, an implicit call is made to the default constructor, ie, it really looks like:

```
public BogusSub() {
     super(); // oops, can't tell which one you want
}
```

To resolve it, provide *typed* versions of your own constructor:

```
public class BogusSub extends BogusSuper {
    public BogusSuper(Collection<String>... a) {
        super(a); // typed to Collection<String>...
    }
    public BogusSuper(String... a) {
        super(a); // typed to String...
    }
}
```

Comment: so the super class `BogusSuper` "loses" its empty default constructor when the other 2 get defined?  In other words, there is no empty constructor for `BogusSuper`?

Comment: I edited the question with BogusSub having its own constructor which does not call out to super(). The error occurs all the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes - that's the other gotcha. The implicit default constructor is only provided if you don't provide *any* constructors (plenty of people have been caught by this, including me).

Comment: @MichaelBraun you cannot define a constructor which doesn't call some form of `super(...)`. If you don't add `super(...)` or `this(...)` call yourself, the compiler will add a call to a no-arg `super()` for you.

Comment: Aha, that's it @Roman - didn't realize the compiler automatically added super calls - and that solved my problem. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have no explicit constructors in `BogusSub`, and the compiler can't work out which of the two varargs constructors in the superclass it should call for the default no-arg constructor it's trying to automatically add for you.

You can make the desired super constructor explicit by adding in a no-arg constructor like so (assuming this is something like what you want):

```
public class BogusSub extends BogusSuper {
  public BogusSub() {
    super(Collections.emptyList());
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a no-arg constructor into `BogusSuper` if this is more appropriate.